# conditional operation on numpy multidimensional array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I am a naive numpy user, need your help for the following problem: I want to replace some elements of a multidimensional array which are less than a second array by a third array; e.g.:

```
x = np.arange(16).reshape((2, 8)) 
# x = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
#               [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

And

```
y = np.array([[2], [13]])
# y = np.array([[ 2], [13]])
```

Now, find out where `x` is greater than `y`, and if there is at least one `True` in `x > y` array, count these instances, create another array (`z`) and replace `x` in these elements with `z`:

```
x > y 
# = [[False, False, False, True,  True,  True,  True, True],
#    [False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True]]
```

In this case 5 elements of `x` (`x[:,3:]`) should be replaced, so we create a `(5, 2)` array:

```
z = np.array([[20,21],[22,23],[24,25],[26,27],[28,29]])
```

The result I want is

```
x == np.array([[ 0,  1,  2, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28],
               [ 8,  9, 10, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `numpy` function that does *almost* exactly what you want is `numpy.where`:

```
x = np.arange(16).reshape((2, 8))
y = np.array([[2], [13]])
z = np.arange(16, 32).reshape((2, 8))
numpy.where(~(x > y).any(axis=0), x, z)
```

Result:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]])
```

The only difference between this and what you asked for is that `z` has to be broadcastable to the same shape as `x`. Unless you *absolutely* need to use a `z` value with only as many columns as there are `True` values in `~(x > y).any(axis=0)`, I think this is the best approach.

However, given your comments, it seems that you do need to use a `z` value as described above. It sounds like the function guarantees that the shapes will match up, so you can probably just do this:

```
x[:,(x > y).any(axis=0)] = z.T
```

Tested:

```
>>> z = np.arange(20, 30).reshape((5, 2))
>>> x[:,(x > y).any(axis=0)] = z.T
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29]])
```

Comment: Thanks @sederle; this returns an error: ValueError: 'shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape' ; I should mention that I don't know shape of the array z ahead.

Comment: @AsoAgile, ok -- but in that case, we need more information about how `z` should be aligned with respect to `x` for purposes of replacement. Is `z` simply a mask as it's treated here? Or is there some kind of sequential logic?

Comment: @sederle; in above example z is (5,2) array created by another function, with first dimension from the number of True (at least one True in x>y), here 5, and second dimention as the first dimension of x, here 2.

Comment: @sederle, your approach worked perfectly for my original question with following modification: 'x[:,(x > y).any(axis=0)] = z.T'; the unknown dimension of z is obtained with: 'np.sum((x > y).any(axis=0))'

Comment: @AsoAgile, ah, I wasn't paying attention to the shape of `z` as you described it. I'll fix it then.